# Can Blazor Server App + MAUI access device?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, maui

Is Blazor Server App runnng in a MAUI WebView going to be able to interact with the native device using something like JS Interop?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely and you don't need JS interop. It just runs on the platform so you can leverage everything that's there.

Depending on your architecture and how you structure your code there is multiple ways to do things. If it's something that is already in Essentials for instance, you can just add .NET MAUI Essentials and use those APIs. I have a video on that [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8W1HSu2-tI0) and the code is [here](https://github.com/jfversluis/MauiBlazorAccessNativeSample).

If you really need to do something else you can leverage the dependency injection. For instance, in the repo I linked (which is mostly a File > New Project), you can see in `MauiProgram.cs` how the `WeatherForecastService` is registered: `builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();`

Now in your Blazor code you can just let that be injected through `@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService` and use it as:

```cs
@code {
    private WeatherForecast[] forecasts;
    private Location location;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

You can make your own service that way to access platform sensors or APIs, inject it like this and use it from Blazor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've actually seen your videos (nice job btw), but I am curious about taking an existing, pure blazor server application, that we want to continue executing server side while rendering to a WebView / BlazorWebView, potentially hosted in maui. As a server hosted model, and here is where I might be missing something, the blazor code executes on the server & only the UI is pushed to the client via Signal-R, the only interaction possible (using this approach) with the WebView hosting control would be JS Interop. something similar to the Old School Javascript window.external.

Comment: Thank you! :) I think you might want to rethink your strategy. If you want to do Blazor server with the hosting still on the server-side, you can do that in a regular WebView as it will just be like any other web app. I think the true power of this is to shift the whole app to a .NET MAUI app and then get your data through a REST API or something similar for both your web hosted Blazor app as well as your .NET MAUI Blazor app

Comment: Yes, this what I expected the answer to be... we just like the idea of our application code never touching the device. Thanks for the clear and quick responses.